# `rbind` dataset by sequence in a directory

Tags: r, path, merge, dataset, rbind

I have a data set with identical row and row numbers. I want to `rbind` those data in a sequence of two.

For example for data `5LSTT-test12_1.avgm` and `5LSTT-test12_1_sum.avgm` 
first I want to merge them by using `rbind` and save them with the new name let's say `test12.avgm`. This process should be done for each two file inside the same directory.

I have checked over the net but most of the solutions for merging the data into a single file. I don't know how to merge two data and save them as single data and do this process all the files in the path.

The data set goes like this

```
5LSTT-test12_1.avgm   
5LSTT-test12_1_sum.avgm  
5LSTT-test13_1.avgm   
5LSTT-test13_1_sum.avgm  
.  
.   
.  
.  
5LSTT-test30_1.avgm   
5LSTT-test30_1_sum.avgm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the vector of object names ('v1') are ordered, we can `split` it to 2 element each list element using `gl`.  I am not sure if these objects are already in the global environment.  In that case, we can use `mget` and replace the `do.call(rbind, lapply(x, read.table)` with `do.call(rbind, mget(x))`

```
lst <- lapply(split(v1,as.numeric(gl(length(v1), 2, length(v1)))), 
               function(x) do.call(rbind,lapply(x, read.table)))
```

Change the names of the 'lst' with 'nm1'

```
nm1 <- sprintf('test%d.avgm', 12:30)
names(lst) <- nm1
```

If we need to create new files, we can do:

```
lapply(seq_along(lst), function(i) write.table(lst[[i]], 
                     paste0(nm1[i],'.txt'), quote=FALSE))
```

#### data

```
v1 <- sort(sprintf('5LSTT-test%d_1.%s', 12:30,
               rep(c('avgm', 'sum.avgm'),each=19)))
```

Comment: works perfect I got the output. Really really appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: Dear @akrun only one small thing the program gave an error when try to open open file '5LSTT-test10_1.-sum.avgm': No such file or directory. How can change the 'sum.avgm' because it tries to read .sum.avgm files but in real the file format is 
"5LSTT-test13_1-sum.avgm"

Comment: @Thabescity  The `nm1` created was of the format `"test12.avgm"`.  Are you saying the files are not in the format `"5LSTT-test12_1.avgm"`.  I may have missed the point.

Comment: @Thabescity  `sprintf('5LSTT-test%d_1-sum.avgm', 12:30)` gives the file names in the format you specified.  Still I didn't quite understand the problem.

Comment: Dear @akrun sorry for delay. yes that part is ok. But when we you used rep(c('avgm', 'sum.avgm') it reads .sum.avgm files. My files in the directory has the format like this 5LSTT-test12_1-sum.avgm

Comment: I think you need to replace `.` with `-`. i.e.  `sort(sprintf('5LSTT-test%d_1-%s', 12:30,rep(c('avgm', 'sum.avgm'),each=19)))`